# Why famine events if the promise was of harvest?

Tags: famine

How to explain God's promise to Noah and his descendants that as long as the Earth lasts, sowing and reaping will not cease with the episodes of famine throughout the Bible?

Comment: It's referring to the seasons of the year, not the fertility of the land.

Comment: There are no seasons for sowing and reaping, there may be a variety of things specific to the climate but not a proper season for planting and harvesting. The seasons were another promise to Noah, logically referring to the fact that if there is sowing, it must be reaped.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.8.22?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.8.22.1&lang2=bi

Comment: L'havdil elef havdalot but I also think pshat in the pesukim is like Rashi. And there definitely are normal sowing and reaping seasons, even if they are different in different climates much the same way there are different times of "day and night" and "hot and cold" and "summer and winter" in different places. Regardless, I suppose you could still ask that sometimes the rainy season isn't rainy, the winter is abnormally warm, etc. I

Comment: I  suppose could say it means that there will never be a GLOBAL disruption of the weather or that things will have a regular cycle, even if sometimes the cycle gets interrupted.

Comment: The idea of the Genesis text concerning the promise that while the Earth lasts, sowing and harvesting would not cease refers to the consequence of if there is sowing it is necessary to have the harvest, if the harvest would not cease at some point it seems that it ceased in the events of famine described throughout the Tanach

Comment: @Avraham Also a good point. I was thinking it's similar to how the promise not to bring another flood was at a global level (see [Sotah 11a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.11a.10)). But Rashi's explanation arguably makes that moot.